# Force to stop spring boot when junit it's over

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

actually i have a Spring Boot application, and i use kafka embedded without use spring-kafka but with the use of confluent library.

I configured the custom Topology, and when i start the junit, the stream remains to listening and spring boot server does not to end.

I tried the use of @DirtiesContext but the problem remains.

For start the junit i use

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

When the consumer is in loop i see this message in console:

> [Producer
>   clientId=application1-3c4587c8-23f0-4c8b-8ef0-75bc1e0f966c-StreamThread-1-producer]
>   Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be
>   available.

Tips?

Thanks

Comment: How do you start the junit? How do you verify that stream is still there? Are you sure that your Kafka instance is not running?

Comment: i've add more details

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error occurs because the broker is not running. But KafkaStreams is running.

In order to fix it, I think you need to prevent KafkaStreams from running when testing.

The @SpringBootTest annotation provides an attribute classes. You can specify the classes that will be registered as beans

You can prevent the KafkaStreams related beans from being registered by specifying the classes attribute.

For example, you can test as follows. In this case, the above problem will not occur because KafkaStreams related beans are not registered.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceImpl.class, CommonConfig.class})
public class SomeClassTest {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl articleServiceImpl;

    // do test
}
```

When you use @SpringBootTest, it is best to register only the beans you want to test.

If you are unfamiliar with this approach, try mocking the bean that manages the KafkaStreams object

For example, I create the following bean to start and end the KafkaStreams object.

```
@Component
public class ManageableStream implements DisposableBean, InitializingBean {

    private final KafkaStreams kafkaStreams;

    public ManageableStream() {
        StreamsConfig config = buildStreamConfig();
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder.stream("source.topic");
        inputStream.to("destination.topic");

        Topology topology = builder.build();
        kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        kafkaStreams.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }

    private StreamsConfig buildStreamConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-stream-application");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, AT_LEAST_ONCE);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class);

        return new StreamsConfig(properties);
    }
}
```

When testing, Mock the bean that manages the KafkaStreams object.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private ManageableStream manageableStream;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Then KafkaStreams will not start, so the above problem will not happen.

If you want to test the topology of KafkaStreams, Please see the link below

https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

I hope my answer was helpful

Comment: Thanks for answers.

i resolved with use of:

@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD, hierarchyMode = DirtiesContext.HierarchyMode.CURRENT_LEVEL)